# Add a button to a treeview row

Tags: button, gtk, cellrenderer, gtktreeview

Is it possible to have a button as a cell renderer in a tree view with gtk2?

There is no documentation of something like a button cell renderer.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to write it yourself. There are probably some open-source applications floating around that do it.